# Darcy Flow - Solution by Finite Difference

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

I'd like to model the fluid flow through a porous medium using finite differences. Since I am new to this numerical technique, I have a simple question.

I use the following set of equations to calculate the change in water volume or porosity over time.

$$q_x = K \frac{dP}{dx}$$

$$q_y = K \left(\frac{dP}{dy} + \varphi g\right)$$

$$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = \frac{q_x}{dx} + \frac{q_y}{dy} $$

where $K$, $P$, $g$, $q$, $\varphi$, $\phi$ are a constant, pressure, gravity, flow velocity, fluid density and porosity.

I know how to solve the groundwater flow equation for fluid flow along the x-axis:

$$\frac{d\phi_{i,j}}{dt} = K \frac{P_{i-1,j} - 2P_{i,j} + P_{i+1,j}}{dx^2 } + ??? $$

But how do I incorporate the gravity term for fluid flow along the y-axis?
Would this be the correct solution?
$$\frac{d\phi_{i,j}}{dt} = K \frac{P_{i-1,j} - 2P_{i,j} + P_{i+1,j}}{dx^2 } + K \frac{P_{i,j-1} - 2P_{i,j} + P_{i,j+1} + \varphi g}{dy^2} $$

Comment: I believe the correct expression for the continuity equation is $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial q_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial q_y}{\partial y}$.

Comment: Thank your for your responses. I was wondering about the gradient in pressure you mentioned. As far as I know groundwater I driven by gravitational and pressure potential energy. In the given equation $$ \dot{Q} = - \frac{K}{\mu} \nabla P $$ you incorporate pressure. How do you incoporate gravitational potential energy and has it an impact only on saturated flows?

Comment: I think that I might understand now why this post is confusing.  The third equation is actually trying to refer to the "filling" of porosity by fluid flux?

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not right.

First, I assume you mean partial derivatives everywhere you have written $d$. Second, your formula:
$$
\frac{d \phi}{dt} = \frac{q_x}{dx} + \frac{q_y}{dy}
$$
should probably be:
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial q_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial q_y}{\partial y}
$$
or
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{q} 
$$
Next, I'm assuming that where you write the gravity term with $\varphi$ you meant to write $\phi$, otherwise, you need to give a definition of $\varphi$.

Finally, given all of the above, you can see that your $y$-direction term should have a first derivative of $\phi$ in it:
$$
\frac{\partial q_y}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(K\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} + \phi g\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(K \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) + g\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}
$$
Here I've assumed that $K$ was only supposed to multiply the first term in the definition of $q_y$, but if it's both, then you should have a $K$ in the coefficient of second term as well.

Based on this, you should have an approximation of the first-derivative of $\phi$ appearing in your formula. Given that this makes this problem a convection-diffusion problem, you may need to be very careful with how you implement that.

Answer (score 1):

First up, all the things Bill said in his answer are spot on.  You have to be fairly rigorous about the nomenclature here.  The old-school expression you see for "Darcys Law" is something like the following:

$$ Q = \frac{-K A}{\mu} \frac{(P_b-P_a)}{L} $$

It is more often presented in the form given by

$$  \dot{Q} = - \frac{K}{\mu} \nabla P $$

which provides a simple stimulus response relationship analogous to Ohm's law in electronics and Fick's law of diffusion. In this presentation, the geometric terms (and gravity!) have been absorbed to produce a 
volumetric flow velocity $\dot{Q}$ in the direction of the gradient of pressure $\nabla P$, linked scalar viscosity and permeability of the media.  Think of gravity as a force that creates a pressure gradient.

Darcy flow is inherently steady state and with a bit of hoop jumping you can get a pair of equations which are solvable to get satisfaction of the Darcy flow law and continuity.  Omitting the math and symbol juggling, you rearrange things to get a pair of equations like this:

$$ \tilde{\nabla} \tilde{P}= \tilde{\nabla}^2 \tilde{v} $$

$$ \tilde{\nabla}^2 \tilde{P}= 0 $$

Which you can descritize into a sparse matrix fairly cleanly or solve by some other methods.  All of this is outlined in my thesis, which just happens to be titled ["Properties of Stochastic Flow and Permeability of Random Porous Media"](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4525748/masters-thesis-related/ms-thesis.pdf).  I have also [implemented a finite-difference solver](https://github.com/meawoppl/ndsolver) that solves these equations in 2, 3 and higher dimensions.

The secret horrible hard part is getting all the BC's right :)